# How to login to Jenkins from any network

Tags: macos, jenkins

I’m an absolute beginner when it comes to setting up a Jenkins environment but I have just installed Jenkins on a MAC v10.15.5 using home-brew and would like the capability to:

- Open a web browser
- Login to Jenkins from any machine on any network
- Trigger a job.

I’m able to do this using a different machine on the same network but unable to do this using a machine on a different network. I changed the "httpListenAddress" value within the jenkins-lts.plist file to 0.0.0.0 to allow the web interface to be accessible from anywhere as mentioned at https://www.macminivault.com/installing-jenkins-on-macos/ but apart from that I’m not sure where to go from here.

I’ve heard about Apache Tomcat but not sure if it's necessary for what I need to do. If anyone can provide instructions / safe approaches about how to login to the Jenkins environment on my MAC from any network that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get jenkins web interface use $JENKINS_HOST_IP:8080 (by default jenkins uses port 8080) and then make first-run-configure.

Login to Jenkins from any machine on any network - it depends on network topology, what is used in your organisation. So, to reach jenkins host from any network where should be allowed traffic from/into network where jenkins host is placed.

Trigger a job - where are a lot of triggers you can use. Take a look at official documentation [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers)